# i have a drill driver that stops working when held at various positions

Tags: drill

i have a Bosch Professional GSR 12 V-15 FC Cordless Drill Driver and when i turn it horizontal or upside down it stops working. Led lights up when trigger pulled but have to shake it to get to work. any ideas on fix?

Comment: return it to the store if under warranty. Open it up and fix a loose wire

Answer (score 2):

Usually a problem with the battery contacts. Make sure the battery fits snuggly, with no play. If  the drill has spring-like contacts, extend the springs just a little bit so that they are always making contact.

Comment: If not, it's a loose contact somewhere inside the drill and you get to go hunting for it.